# Missing or Invalid signature .The bundle 'com.company.appname' at bundle path 'appname.app' is not signed using an apple submission certificate

Tags: ios

I am getting this error while uploading new app and also while updating.I reinstalled all my certificates.Please let me know why i am facing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get the certificates from?

If certSigningRequest is not generated from your system, then you will have to use exported one. Direct download from developer.apple.com won't work for you.

Comment: Hello 

I am downloading the certificates from the same system where i am trying to upload.I have regenerated all my certificates from developer.apple.com...I am able to develop apps and build in device but the distribution is only giving this issue.




Thanks..:)